# Calculate the percent composition of a sodium carbonate/sodium bicarbonate mixture

Tags: analytical-chemistry, stoichiometry

> In a lab, we titrated a solid mixture of sodium carbonate and sodium bicarbonate with $\pu{0.1 M}\ \ce{ HCl}$. We are asked to calculate the percent composition by mass of sodium carbonate and sodium bicarbonate.
>
> **Data:**
>
> - Unknown mass used: $\pu{0.107 g}$
> - Volume of $\ce{HCl}$ used: $\pu{16.6 mL}$

Here was my approach:

**1)** I determined the moles of carbonate by doing the following:

$$(\pu{16.6 mL} \ \ce{HCl}) \times \frac{\pu{1L}}{\pu{1000 mL}} \times  \frac{\pu{0.1 mol}\ \ce{HCl}}{\pu{1 L}\ \ce{HCl}} \times  \frac{\pu{1 mol}\ \text{carbonate}}{\pu{1 mol}\ \ce{HCl}} = \pu{0.00166 mol}\ \text{of carbonate}$$

**2)** I calculated the molar mass of sodium carbonate and sodium bicarbonate:

MM of sodium carbonate $= \pu{105.99 g/mol}$

MM of sodium bicarbonate $= \pu{84.01 g/mol}$

**3)** This is the part I'm unsure about. I said that

$$\frac{x}{\pu{105.99 g/mol}} + \frac{(0.107 - x)}{\pu{84.01 g/mol}} = \pu{0.00166 mol}\ \text{of carbonate}$$

Doing this math, I determined that the compound was 52% sodium carbonate and 48% sodium bicarbonate but I'm unsure if this is correct.

The instructor seemed to want us to solve it in terms of H+ using the following ratios:

- $\pu{1 mol}$ of carbonate: $\pu{2 mol}$ of $\ce{H+}$
- $\pu{1 mol}$ of bicarbonate: $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{H+}$

but I'm not sure how you would use this information to answer the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your work in step 3, you have treated both carbonate and bicarbonate equally. That contradicts what your teacher has said.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure how to write an equation that treats them "unequally". Would saying that 2 moles of carbonate and 1 mol of bicarbonate = 1 mol H+ be correct?

Comment: Not correct. Each mole of carbonate counts for two moles of $\ce{HCl}$.

Comment: Ah I see. So                                                                                                             1 mol Na2CO3: 2 mol HCl                                                                                   
and                                                                                                                           1 mol NaHCO3: 1 mol HCl are the correct ratios?                                             From there I can calculate the number of moles of each, convert to grams, and then say that 0.107 grams = x(grams of Na2CO3) + (1-x)(grams of NaHCO3)?

Comment: Your modified approach is fine but your teacher is teaching this analytical method the wrong way. No wonder students are confused. What happens in reality is that you use $two$ indicators in steps. One indicator shows the end-point when all carbonate is converted to NaHCO3. Then we add another indicator to titrate all the bicarbonate. Google "Lab 2: Determination of Carbonate/Bicarbonate." The assumption  0.107 grams = x(grams of Na2CO3) + (1-x)(grams of NaHCO3) should never be used in any real analysis, because we are assuming that the sample is pure i.e. made of only two components.

Comment: Thank you both for the help and resource suggestions!